# Android - Converting nested Maps to JSON String

Tags: java, android, json, gson

My app does HTTP requests using [this `GsonRequest`](http://pastebin.com/aZzEe0vn) implementation.
Some of the requests parameters are not simple string keys and string values, but some values can be a map too.

For instance:

```
{
    "Key1" : "value",
    "Key2" : {
        "Key2.1" : "value",
        "Key2.2" : "value",
        "Key2.2" : "value"
    },
    "Key3" : "value"
}
```

The JSON parameters above can be built using `HashMap`s like this:

```
Map<String, String> subMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

subMap.put("Key2.1", "value");
subMap.put("Key2.2", "value");
subMap.put("Key2.3", "value");

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("Key1", "value");
map.put("Key2", subMap.toString());
map.put("Key3", "value");
```

And then I call `GsonRequest` and pass `map`.

However, when the request is made, the JSON sent is actually:

```
{
    "Key1" : "value",
    "Key2" : "{Key2.1 = value, Key2.2 = value, Key2.2 = value}", <-- This is wrong
    "Key3" : "value"
}
```

I tried to nest the maps using a `JSONObject`, with no success:

```
map.put("Key2.2", new JSONObject(subMap).toString());
```

will produce the  JSON:

```
...
"Key2" : "{\"Key2.1\" : \"value\", \"Key2.2\" : \"value\", \"Key2.2\" : \"value\"}",
...
```

This one looks better, if I could escape the slashes it'd be right, but no.

How can I nest the maps properly and get the JSON correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thinking for a while, I realized that nesting `Strings` was wrong and that should not be used. But I was using that because the class `Request`, which my `GsonRequest` extends, requires a `HashMap<String, String>` map for the parameters.

What I did was to force the passage of a `HashMap<String, Object>` map. I didn't expected it to work, but I needed to give it a try. And it did work.